# Does Thymeleaf's th:field generate an id attribute too?

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have this in my browser console (in fact, many similar messages):

```
[DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #username: (More info: /* some URL */)
<input id="username" class="form-control" min="2" max="15" aria-describedby="uu-username-help-block" required="" name="username" value="scrooge_m">
<input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="scrooge_m">
```

But in my HTML there's no `<input type="hidden" id="username" name="username" value="scrooge_m">`. Instead, I have `<input type="hidden" th:field="*{username}"/>` which was expected to translate into `<input type="hidden" name="username" value="scrooge_m">`, no `id` specified. I am afraid non-unique `id`s may cause issues so I would like to resolve it

**Does Thymeleaf's `th:field` generate an id attribute too? If so, how to I avoid these automatically generated `id`s? If not, why do I not have these non-unique `id`s in my IDE but have them in the browser?**

ChatGPT 3 says `th:field` doesn't generate an `id`, but Sage says it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in the [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/thymeleafspring.html#inputs) what is generated when you use `th:field`:

> ```
> <input type="text" th:field="*{datePlanted}" />
> ```
>
> As you can see, we are introducing a new attribute here: th:field. This is a very important feature for Spring MVC integration because it does all the heavy work of binding your input with a property in the form-backing bean. You can see it as an equivalent of the path attribute in a tag from Spring MVC’s JSP tag library.
>
> The th:field attribute behaves differently depending on whether it is attached to an ,  or  tag (and also depending on the specific type of  tag). In this case (input[type=text]), the above line of code is similar to:
>
> ```
> <input type="text" id="datePlanted" name="datePlanted" th:value="*{datePlanted}" />
> ```

It generates the `id`, `name` and `th:value`.

I wouldn't give up the functionality of `th:field` because of the possibility of duplicate `id` values.  And if you are worried about them, yes you can specify the id in the tag.  This works for example:

```
<input id="unique-id-here" type="hidden" th:field="*{username}"/>
```

Thymeleaf will not overwrite your id (or `th:id`, or `th:attr="id='...'"`).

Comment: Thank you! Don't you think it was ill-advised of Thymeleaf to make `th:field` generate `id`s (which often happen to be non-unique)?

Comment: I'm not sure I see the case where it will generate duplicate ids... if you have `th:field="*{username}"` you should know not to have `id="username"` elsewhere in your html.  The fact that `th:field` generates a known id is also helpful when doing stuff like `<label for="username">Username</label>` which depends on the form field having `id="username"`.

Comment: It happened in my case because I forEach'ed a `List` of `User`s so e.g. `${user.username}` occurred as many times as the number of `User`s on the `List`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Thymeleaf makes a name for a form field, like "username," and it also makes an ID for it so the computer can remember it. If you don't want Thymeleaf to make the ID, you can tell it what ID to use.
you can use the th:attr attribute to explicitly set the id attribute like this

```html
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{username}" th:attr="id='my-username'"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. A couple of questions: 1) maybe I should avoid `th:field` altogether? `th:value` doesn't generate an `id`, does it? 2) would `id="my-id"` suffice? Do I really need `th:attr="id='my-username'"`?

Comment: The th:value attribute sets the value of the input field without generating the name or id attributes. <input type="hidden" name="username" th:value="${myVariable}" />